# Is there a simple way to create events and listeners in React Native

Tags: javascript, events, react-native, publish-subscribe, event-listener

Is there a simple way to create events and listeners in React Native.  I have a realm database service component that I import into my other view components (its not a parent or child relationship) and I want to be able to trigger my view component to show a spinner when I start comms with the back end server and stop the spinner when its completed (could be triggered by a button but might be triggered by a timer).

Realm has its own onchange event which I can register a listener to but that doesnt cover all my scenarios.

Is there a simple way of doing event and listener?  I suspect I am missing something and that since I import the service into the component I should be able to pass through functions to call back.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: You could use something like mobX or redux to fire events that indicate when communication starts and is complete.